# When I use sudo command, it returns "Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-9!"

Tags: sudo

My system is RHEL 6.7,
Output of `echo $PATH`

```
[geoeast@hp2-12 ~]$ which rm
rm:      aliased to rm -i
[geoeast@hp2-12 ~]$ which cp
cp:      aliased to cp -i
[geoeast@hp2-12 ~]$ echo $PATH
/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/lightning/build/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/gstomo/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/diva/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/lightning/build/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/diva/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/gstomo/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/support/fontforge/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/support/tools/bin:.:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/GeoGME:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/vsp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sfp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/cshell:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdppy:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/statics:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/int:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/mc:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/ggi:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/zookeeper/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/install:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/batp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/nap:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ndp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ncp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ncld:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/common:/soft/ieco1.0.3/GeoSeisIO/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/ivtms/console:/soft/ieco1.0.3/licmng/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/tools/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/python/gbin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/cwp/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mojoview/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/DDS.2011-07-15/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/PCG/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/gslib90/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/qcad:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/qt3/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/ImageMagick/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/jdk/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mysql/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/oiv/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/ora/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/postgresql/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mvapich2.tcp/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin
```

Here is the example:

```
[geoeast@hp2-12 /tmp]$ sudo rm test2
Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-9!
```

`sudo cp -a` returns the same error.

```
[geoeast@hp2-12 /tmp]$ sudo cp -a seismicview.log seismicview.log2
Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-9!
```

It works with another user:

```
[geoeast@hp2-12 /tmp]$ su geou1
Password: 
[geou1@hp2-12 /tmp]$ sudo cp -a seismicview.log seismicview.log2
[sudo] password for geou1: 
[geou1@hp2-12 /tmp]$
```

Output of geou1 `echo $PATH`

```
[geou1@hp2-12 /tmp]$ echo $PATH
.:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/fcitx/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/fcitx/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/GJSS/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/ora/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/dp:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/GeoSeisIO/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/jsf:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/vsp:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/sfp:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/sdp/int:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/sdp/cshell:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/sdp/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/systools:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/mc:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/gsm:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/GJSS/gjssgui:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/GJSS:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/bin/ggi:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/firefox:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/qcad:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/Adobe/Reader9/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/Firefly/Client/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/jdk/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/qt3/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/mysql/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/oiv/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/ora/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/postgresql/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/ImageMagick/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/tools/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/pyt/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/mpi/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/cwp/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/cuda/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/petsc/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/mojoview/bin:/soft/geoeast3.0.5/support/paraview/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/GNQS/sbin:/usr/GNQS/bin
```

What should I do to make `sudo` command work?

Comment: What is the output of `which rm`, `which cp`, and `echo $PATH` for the geoeast user?

Comment: @JG7 I updated the post with the output.

Comment: cat /etc/sudoers

Comment: @gapsf sudoers is a very long file, but `geoeast ALL=(ALL)  ALL` is in this file. This is also in the sudoers file: `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/packaging_guide/sect-unable_to_open_etc_scl_prefixes_software_collection_name

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/scl

Comment: @roaima result added.

Answer (score 0):

The user account that generates the error, `Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-9!` has the directory `/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin` in their `$PATH` (the list of directories that are searched for commands). On the other hand, the user account that works successfully, `geou1`, does not contain this directory.

I would surmise therefore that the `sudo` your first user is executing is actually in that that extra directory, and it is this that is trying to access `/etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-9`. (You can check this with `type sudo` and confirming that it is not in `/usr/bin`.)

These directories look like they have been added by an institution, so the bet solution would be to report the problem to the IT Servicedesk or System Administrators for them to fix.

Another approach might be to remove the `/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin` directory from your `$PATH` so that the unofficial version of `sudo` isn't executed at all. However, I could not tell you what that might break.

```
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed 's!:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin:!:!g')
```

While you're there, I would *strongly* recommend you removing `.` from the list of directories in your `$PATH`.

```
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed 's!:\.:!:!g')
```

Alternatively, reorder the list of directories so that the system directories are listed first. Here, I've reordered them, removed the duplicate entries, and also taken out `.`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/lightning/build/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/gstomo/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/diva/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/lightning/build/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/opt/gstomo/Linux.x86_64/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/support/fontforge/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/support/tools/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/GeoGME:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/vsp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sfp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/cshell:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdppy:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/statics:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/bin:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp/int:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/sdp:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/mc:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/cw:/soft/geoeast4.0.3/bin/ggi:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/zookeeper/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/install:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/batp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/nap:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ndp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ncp:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/ncld:/soft/ieco1.0.3/bin/common:/soft/ieco1.0.3/GeoSeisIO/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/ivtms/console:/soft/ieco1.0.3/licmng/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/tools/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/python/gbin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/cwp/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mojoview/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/DDS.2011-07-15/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/PCG/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/gslib90/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/qcad:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/qt3/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/ImageMagick/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/jdk/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mysql/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/oiv/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/ora/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/postgresql/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/mvapich2.tcp/bin:/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin
```

Comment: I definitely cannot remove the `/soft/ieco1.0.3.....` directory from PATH. But is it gonna work if I just copy `/usr/bin/sudo` into the `/soft/ieco1.0.3/support_2.6.32/devtoolset-9_as6/root/usr/bin` folder?

Comment: @obnews If you make the copy you will have to confirm that the new path is still suid root but I don't think putting the binary elsewhere will help. Does it help if you use an absolute path, e.g., `sudo /bin/rm test2`?

Comment: It would be better to reorder the PATH components as suggested in my answer

Comment: @doneal24 It actually working if I use it like `/usr/bin/sudo rm test2`

Comment: Yes. So reorder the PATH components like I've suggested